# Selectet data and data from with(), Laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

I want to select some columns and some data from `with()`, the problem is that I get only data from `select()`.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));

$contracts = Contract::select('
    'contracts.id',
    'contracts.contract_value_exc_VAT_total',
    'customers.account_name',
    'users.name',
    )
    ->whereHas('dates', function($q) use($today){
        return $q->whereDate('date', '>=', $today)
            ->where(function($q) {
                $q->where('lkp_contract_date_tag_id', 4)
                    ->orwhere('lkp_contract_date_tag_id', 7);
            });
    })
    ->with(['dates' => function($q){
        $q->select('id', 'date');
    }])
    ->join('customers','contracts.customer_id', 'customers.id')
    ->leftJoin('users','contracts.account_manager_select', 'users.id')
    ->get();

return response()->json($contracts);
```

**From response, dates are null**

```
//date....
dates: []
//date...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without using the `select()`

You can have the relations in the `ContractModel`. You can always process the data after getting from the database and manipulate it in a format you want to return.

There are two options to do that

- Do it here in the controller itself.
- Create an API resource for the Contract. (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#introduction)

I would suggest the latter as it's more convenient.

For both of them you need to do this first. Make some changes in the contract model.

ContractModel.php

```
// I'm assuming that you have dates relation in the contract(because you've added it in the `with()` for eager loading.)

public function dates(){
...
}

 // Instead of joining while doing the query, add the following 
 // relations in the contract as well.

public function customer(){
    return $belongsTo('App\Customer', 'customer_id', 'id');
}

public function accountManagerSelect(){
    return $belongsTo('App\User', 'account_manager_select', 'id');
}
```

This is how you go with the API resource approach.

Create the Contract Api Resource. And this is how the toArray() method should be.

```
toArray() {
  // Get the dates in the format you want. I'have added the below 
  // format by considering the 'select' statement you added for 
  // dates.

  $dates = [];
  // will use the relation dates, to get the associated dates.
  foreach($this->dates as $date){
     array_push($dates, [
         'id' => $date->id,
         'date' => $date->date,
     ]);
  }


  return [
    'id' => $this->id, // id of the contract.
    'contract_value_exc_VAT_total' => $this
                              ->contract_value_exc_VAT_total, 
    'account_name' => $this->account_name, 
     // This will use the accountManagerSelect relation to get the 
     // User instance and then you can access the name from that.
    'name' => $this->accountManagerSelect->name,
    'dates' => $dates, // The dates variable that we created earlier.
   ];
}
```

All you need to do is return using API resource in your controller.

instead of doing this

```
return response()->json($contracts);
```

Use Api resource

```
return ContractResource::collection($contracts);
```

Comment: Let me know if i got your question wrong or if you need any help with the query too. @Beusebiu